# Delphi Compiler optimization removes class from binary file

Tags: delphi, compiler-optimization, rtti

I have been able to decouple my code so that the compiler thinks that classes are not used in the application, even if they are.
I have a mechanism registring classes based on their attributes.

Currently I have solved this by referencing the class in the unit with the classes definition, like so:

```
interface
uses
  uISomeService;

type
  [ServiceName('FooBar')]
  [LicenseKey('LIC42')]
  TSomeService1 = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeService)
  ...
  end;

  ...
  ...
implementation

 ...
procedure Donothing(AClass: Tclass);
  begin
    // Do nothing
  end;

initialization
 Donothing(TSomeService1);
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler to **"include this class in the binary even if you think it is not used"**  something like `{$NoClassOpti + }` ? I do not like the use of a procedure call in initialization.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054460/creating-a-delphi-ioc-how-to-disable-delphis-linker-from-removing-unused-class). There is only a [global setting](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Strong_link_types_(Delphi)), not per class.

Comment: Thank you @Olivier, that is actually my problem, almost exactly.
Hmm, I do like the {$STRONGLINKTYPES ON} directive, but I do not like the idea to add it in the .dpr. Anyway, thanks for the link, mush appreciated.

Comment: I always solve this problem by having a unit with a single empty function `procedure IncludeClasses(const Classes: array of TMyBaseClass);` (or an application-specific naming convention) in its implementation section and a `IncludeClasses([TMyClass1, TMyClass2, ...])`, nicely formatted with one class per line, in the `initialization` section. Of course, the implementation section's `uses` clause will contain the relevant units. I prefer this approach because it feels semantic; "do nothing", although technically correct, feels wrong.

Comment: @Olivier, seems like a can not mark your comment as a solution. Perhaps if you made it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You already found two suitable solutions to your issue.

There is a third one: add a public class method doing nothing in TSomeService1 and call the class method from the initialization section. Give it a name explaining why this method exist.

This is almost the same as your DoNothing procedure and both will work as long as the compiler/linker are not smart enough to eliminate call to empty procedure/method.

Comment: Yes, that is another version of the same approach. Might even be a bit better. 
I wouldn't say the solutions are "suitable", more like "usable".